# key error:102 in sklearn

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I use Naive Bayes algorithm. It has negative and positive reviews and I am doing sentimental analysis on the data.

```
df=pd.DataFrame()
df=pd.read_csv('Data.tsv',delimiter='\t',quoting=3,engine='python')
df=df.dropna()
df=df.reindex(np.random.permutation(df.index))
corpus=[]
for i in range(len(df)):
    review=re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]',' ',df['review'][i])
    review=review.lower()
    review=review.split()
    ps=PorterStemmer()
    review=[ps.stem(word) for word in review if not word  in  set(stopwords.words('english'))]
    review=' '.join(review)
    corpus.append(review)
```

Error must be here because i get all results up to corpus. I get

```
File "pandas\hashtable.pyx", line 309, in pandas.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item (pandas\hashtable.c:6554)
KeyError: 102
```

#### Code

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
cv = CountVectorizer(max_features =135)
X = cv.fit_transform(corpus).toarray()
y = df.iloc[:, 1].values
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small demo, where we will use a `movie review` corpus provided by NLTK module.

Output:

```
Fitting 3 folds for each of 24 candidates, totalling 72 fits
[CV] MultinomNB__alpha=0.001, vect__analyzer=char_wb, vect__min_df=1, vect__ngram_range=(1, 1)
[CV] MultinomNB__alpha=0.001, vect__analyzer=char_wb, vect__min_df=1, vect__ngram_range=(1, 1)
[CV] MultinomNB__alpha=0.001, vect__analyzer=char_wb, vect__min_df=1, vect__ngram_range=(1, 1)
...
skipped
...
[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done  72 out of  72 | elapsed:  6.1min finished
Best parameters: {'MultinomNB__alpha': 1, 'vect__analyzer': 'char_wb', 'vect__min_df': 1, 'vect__ngram_range': (2, 5)}

             precision    recall  f1-score   support

        neg       0.77      0.85      0.81       146
        pos       0.84      0.75      0.79       154

avg / total       0.80      0.80      0.80       300
```

Full code:

```
from pathlib import Path
from nltk import word_tokenize, sent_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords, movie_reviews
from nltk.stem.porter import PorterStemmer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.externals import joblib

stop = set(stopwords.words('english'))
ps = PorterStemmer()

# read moview reviews data set from NLTK
df =  pd.DataFrame([[category, Path(movie_reviews.abspath(fileid))
                                .read_text().casefold()]
                    for category in movie_reviews.categories()
                    for fileid in movie_reviews.fileids(category)],
                   columns=['category','review'])

df['review'] = df['review'].str.replace(r'[^a-zA-Z]', ' ')

# replace all words with their stemmed form    
X = [' '.join([ps.stem(w) for w in word_tokenize(review)
      if w not in stop])
     for review in df['review'].values]
y = df['category'].map({'pos':1, 'neg':-1})

# split data set into train and test parts                     
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.15)

# build a pipeline: vectorize and fit `MultinomNB` classifier
pipeline = Pipeline([
             ('vect', CountVectorizer()),
             ('MultinomNB', MultinomialNB()) ])

# prepare a grid of hyperparameters    
param_grid = dict(vect__min_df=[1,3],
                  vect__ngram_range=[(1,1),(2,4),(2,5)],
                  vect__analyzer=['char_wb'],
                  MultinomNB__alpha=[0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1])
# use 3 folds, use all available CPUs, be verbose
grid_search = GridSearchCV(pipeline, param_grid=param_grid, cv=3, n_jobs=-1, verbose=2)

# find best hyperparameters    
grid_search.fit(X_train, y_train)
# save trained model into Pickle file
joblib.dump(grid_search, r'c:/temp/grid_search_49192570.pkl') 
# print best values for the hyperparameters
print('Best parameters: {}'.format(grid_search.best_params_))
# predict categories for the "unseen" test data set
y_pred = grid_search.best_estimator_.predict(X_test)
# show the main classification metrics
print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred, target_names=['neg','pos']))
```

Comment: Dont we have to use algorithm like Naive Bayes??.I just started with NLP..